# Get "Folder Access Permission" in WinJS

Tags: permissions, directory, winjs

I'm building an app that has projects. A project can have many files in it which are pointed to from a project file. Theses files are copied to the projects folder so I know where they will be but as far as I know in WinJS you can only get access to files the user directly give access to. The user will select the project file, I'll be able to read it but I'll have no way to access the projects files. I do know I can do something like package the project up as a single file and then extract the individual files in my apps local file system but doing so is sub-optimal to me and I'd prefer to do the folder based structure if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I get it, but I'll give it a shot. In a Windows Store app, you do have access to more than just what the user directly gives access to. If you want to pick a file from anywhere on the computer (our from other apps through the FilePicker contract) then, yes, the user has to pick them, but you app has full access to the isolated storage and if it declares access to the user's documents library and the user allows it, then you have access (to your declared file types) in there as well.

I think the choice of going to isolated storage versus the user's document library comes down to whether or not the user would expect to have the project files outside of your app. Might they email a project to a friend? Might they manipulate the project with another app? Might they want to back the project up? If so, then use their documents library. If not, then the data is more *application data* than *user data* and could be stored in the local app storage.
Hope that answers the question. If not, then please clarify.